# Dimensional analysis of magnetic energy: dimensions of µ0 and H

Tags: thermodynamics, superconductivity, magnetic-fields, dimensional-analysis, si-units

When calculating the energy difference between the normal and the superconducting state in a superconductor at zero magnetic field, the result is as follows:

[image]

Now I'm quite confident of this result, as it is the same as my textbook tells me it is. The problem is that when I do a dimensional analysis, I find

[image]

The dimension on the left is energy, the dimension on the right is vacuum permeability times H-field squared. The units of the first are found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permeability), $N/A^2$, as are the units of the second, [$A/m$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field_strength) (Ctrl+F for *``The H-field is measured in''*).

As you can see, the lengths don't cancel out, we have $[L]^2$ on the left and $[L]^{-1}$ on the right. What am I doing wrong? Is the first equation not in SI?

---

*Edit:* In case it might be of any help, the derivation of the above equation is (using the Meissner effect in the final step, $M=-H$) as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that your expression gives the energy difference **per unit volume**. So you need an additional factor of $\left[L^{-3}\right]$ on the left hand side.

Comment: That was exactly what I found a minute ago, you beat me to it :p.

Comment: @Betohaku Great! I find it's always more rewarding to get to that Aha-moment on my own. So I haven't robbed you of that :)

Comment: Just a bit frustrating that the authors use the term *Gibbs energy* instead of *Gibbs energy density*..

Comment: Yeah, it can sometimes be a cause for confusion when authors make things like that implicit. Especially when you're first learning about something, it's important to stop at every equation you come across and think: what exactly am I looking at here? Doing some quick dimensional analysis as you have done for this equation is a useful thing (and a good habit) in that respect, especially for relatively simple equations. For more complicated equations dimensional analysis can take some time, though you should still do it when in doubt.